# Javascript variable to div

Tags: javascript, variables, post

I've just start using javascript. How can I exactly send a variable to a div? I tried the following, this is my javascript code:

```
$("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function(e, data){
    console.log("min: " + data.values.min + " max: " + data.values.max);
});
```

So I want to see the variables like `data.values.min` and `data.values.max` in a div. So then I tried:

`$("#test").text(data.values.min)` and I tried `$("#test").text(valuesChanged)`

But none of those will send the value to the `<div id="test"></div>`. How to do this?

Comment: Where have you found this "`valuesChanged`" event?

Comment: @Teemu Well it's part of a range slider: http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html#valuesChangedEvent

Comment: @Teemu What I want to do must be simple, I'm trying to parse the min and max values to html.

Comment: Oh, I see, maybe it's better to mention it in the question, or even tag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are using following source

**[Slider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/documentation.html)** to implement slider

Try this

```
$("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function(e, data){
    $("#test").html("min: " + data.values.min + " max: " + data.values.max);
});
```

If it doesn't works, try to alert the values first like following

```
$("#slider").bind("valuesChanged", function(e, data)
{
 alert(data.values.min);
});
```

If alert is triggered it means you have some library related issues.

Comment: @K D Thanks, the first one worked indeed. I'm beginning to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use .html() method.

```
$("#test").html("test");
```